# Docker build image Prestashop

Tags: docker

I'm a Docker beginner. I have pull and configured, installed Prestashop in my docker container.
I would like to build an image with this config.
How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To build a container you would have to run docker build -t myawsome_container:1.0.0 . (providing that you are in the directory where your Dockerfile is located)

Now to run your container you would want to run docker run myawsome_container:1.0.0

Comment: I don't want build container I want build image from container pre configured